# How to make data visible for all view controllers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller

Let's consider the following case:

I have a tab bar application where tapping each tab bar item takes user to other view that is handled by different view controller(typical pattern).

In one of my controllers I have method that downloads the important data and I want them to be global for whole application. What design pattern should I use?

One way to do that is to store this data using persistence such as core data, but is it the only way to make data visible for all view controllers? Maybe app delegate is able to perform such actions?

How in general you solve such situation where you have some data or variable which should be visible for all view controllers in your project?

Note that I'm not asking about persisting data across launches of the app, I just wonder how to make some data global in terms of the whole project.

Comment: You could possibly use a Singleton object, but the data wont persist across launches. CoreData really was designed to do what you're talking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Dont (emphasize DON'T) use following:

- Singletons
- AppDelegate (just another Singleton)
- NSUserDefaults

#### Rather Don't:

- Core Data

#### Do:

- pass in either during instantiation or via properties

#### Why?

The DON'Ts messes up your memory
the Rather Don't messes with several principals of [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)).

#### How would you do it correctly:

- Create a base view controller that has a property that takes your data, make all your view controller inherit from it.
- subclass UITabBarController
- if a new view controller is selected, set the data to the view controller

the implementation is a bit tricky, this is from a real world app

```
class ContentTabBarController : UITabBarController {
    
    private var kvoSelectedViewControllerContext: UInt8 = 1
    
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        
   
        self.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "selectedViewController", options: .New | .Old | .Initial , context: &kvoSelectedViewControllerContext)
    }
    
    deinit{
        self.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "selectedViewController")
    }
    
    override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String, ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [NSObject : AnyObject], context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
        if context == &kvoSelectedViewControllerContext {
            var targetVC : UIViewController?

            if let viewController = change["new"] as? UIViewController{
                if let oldViewController = change["old"] as? UIViewController{
                    if viewController != oldViewController {
                        targetVC = viewController
                    }
                }
            } else {
                targetVC = self.viewControllers![0] as? UIViewController
            }
            self.configureTargetViewController(targetVC)
        }
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = false
    }

    func configureTargetViewController(viewController: UIViewController?){

        //setup data
    }
}
```

#### How does the tab bar controller get the data.

Well, that is up to you. It could fetch core data, it could actually pass a fetching manager as data. It could read from disc or network. But for a sane design it should not do it itself but use another class for it. and an instance of this fetcher class should be set from outside the tab bar controller, i.e. from the App Delegate.

Comment: This answer is very interesting indeed. As you mentioned above, the implementation is tricky as hell for me. However, is your approach a default one when dealing with such situation? I think sharing data for more than one controller is quite ordinary when developing apps and I can hardly imagine that apple didn't come up with some more straightforward way to do this. Could you elaborate why using singleton or core data are messing memory? Thanks for your reply!

Comment: lets say you pass data from one vc to another vc via singleton, what will happen to the data once both VCs are done and gone? it hangs around. Same with NSUserDefaults. even worse: it survives even app restarts. Core Data are just normal objects. It matters how you pass them around. but accessing core data from with in a VC violates the open close principle of SOLID as it hides the dependency.

Comment: apple gives us property injection: just inject objects you in a VC need by assigning it to a property. this is sane approach und works universally. Your requirement of making data available throughout the app makes it tricky.

Comment: Let's research the ios provided app "music". It has 4 tab items (song, artists etc.) and each one takes you to the different table view with the same data just presented the other way. I guess this is done via core data, am I right?

Comment: probably it is done by passing around accessor objects that can fetch and hold data from any source. and combine sources, as the files surely o not belong into core data. or the data is yet to be fetched from network.The VCs won't know and won't care where the data is coming from. The accessors hide this from them.

Comment: I'm not sure if I get what exactly are "accessor objects" Could you provide some resources or maybe even there is some kind of tutorial that pertains to such problems?

Comment: one principle in software architecture is the Single Responsibility Principle: each class should have just one purpose. Or: there should be only one reason why a class might change. a VC should only control views. If data is needed in that process, it should not take care of getting them. Instead it should ask another distinct object to access the data for it: a data accessor.

Comment: This might be helpful http://oleb.net/blog/2014/06/apples-take-on-app-architecture/ and this https://github.com/vikingosegundo/ofapopulator

Comment: Thanks for the resources, now I feel like I'm standing on the first yard of really long learning path:)

Comment: The biggest problem is that usually apple doesn't focus on good architecture in there tutorials. They only focus on certain aspects. If it is about MapKit, it will show how to display a map, but all other codes in that tutorial are just coded somehow fast. No word that datasources are always better off in own classes. But still many developers take these codes as blueprints for their projects without any thought. My advice: SOLID are the single most important principles to create good architectures. Study and understand them. If you understand and apply them you will write good code instantly.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way would be to make a struct and make it hold variables. Then, you can edit it anytime you would want to. For example:

```
struct Variables {
   static var number = 4
}
```

Then you can edit the data inside Variables in any view controller you want by doing this code.

```
Variables.number = 6 //or any other number you want
```

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner and efficient, although not necessarily different, way to do this is to create a **singleton class**, e.g. `AppData`, which you can access in a variety of ways, and which would be available to all your other classes. It has the benefit of separating your app-specific stuff from the app delegate stuff. You might define the class this way:

```
@interface AppData : NSObject

// Perhaps you'll declare some class methods here & objects...

@end
```

you can define ivars for the AppData class, and then manage a singleton instance of AppData. Use a class method, e.g. **+sharedInstance**, to get a handle to the singleton on which you could then call mehods. For example,

```
[[AppData sharedInstance] someMethod:myArgument];
```

Your implementation of **+sharedInstance** can be where you manage the actual creation of the singleton, which the method ultimately returns.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple method,

1) Create a variable in appdelegate.swift that could be visible to all viewcontroller.

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

 ...
 ...
 var Check:String!="" // to pass string
 ...
 ...    
}
```

2) Create appdelegate instance in any viewcontroller

**viewcontroller1.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

   ...
   ...

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ...
    var tmp = "\(appDelegate.Check)"
    appDelegate.Check="Modified"
    }
}
```

**Viewcontroller2.swift**

```
import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

       ...
       ...

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            ...
        var getdata = "\(appDelegate.Check)"
        println("Check data : \(getdata)") // Output : Check data : Modified
        }
    }
```